# price configurable product

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, price

I'm making a Magento webshop and I wondered what is best way to implement the following scenario:

Product A is a configurable product which can be fitted with some options and additional related products. This was quite easy to implement, though the thing is that there are fitting costs for product A, which is also quite easy to implement, but the fitting costs are also related to the additional related products that are chosen.

So for instance:

I'm buying product A with fitting costs of 10 euro's. Then I'm adding additional related product B and the fitting costs for that one is 5 euro's. Then the total fitting costs of product A and the additional related product B should be 15 euro's. People can choose to either let the company do the fitting or that the customer itself does the fitting. It the customer wants to do it him/herself there should be no fitting costs.

I've tried some things, but I can't really make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with standard Magento and honestly, an extension that allows this is pretty complicated I think.

Perhaps going with a bundled product would be a way to solve it.

**[option 1]**

- Choose your product A variation 1
- Choose your product A variation 2
- Choose your product A variation 3
- Choose your product A variation ...

**[option 2]**

- Added relational product 1
- Added relational product 1 + fitting costs

**[option 3]**

- Added relational product 2
- Added relational product 2 + fitting costs